# How to enable evil-mc with helm-ag-edit and helm-swoop-edit?

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I want to use multiple cursors in buffer of `helm-ag-edit` and `helm-swoop-edit`. But It couldn't auto enable `evil-mc-mode`. I added:

```
(dolist (buffer '("*helm-ag-edit*" "*Helm Swoop Edit*"))
  (when (get-buffer buffer)
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (evil-mc-mode 1))))
```

Unfortunately，it has not any effect. So how to auto enable`evil-mc-mode` with these two buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it is not too late for my reply.
I encountered the same problem and finally realised that I do not need evil-mc at all!
This is how I work with *-edit buffers:

- invoke helm-ag, helm-swoop
- C-c C-e to enter edition of the *-edit buffer
- **M %**
- insert query string and it's replacement (use M-n to navigate prompt's history and get string already used for search operation)
- RET
- y to replace one match
- n to skip one match
- ! to replace all remaining matches

**Pros:** You do not have to jump to the string location

**Cons:** You will have to specify the string and it's replacement

**Hint:** press ? to see the *-edit buffer manual

Emacs is awesome!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I have found a way to use evil-mc.`(advice-add 'helm-swoop--edit :after #'evil-mc-mode)` and `(advice-add 'helm-ag--edit :after #'evil-mc-mode)`. I don't know why but it really work well.

Comment: @honmaple you should post this as the answer, because that is what you were actually looking for, it would also help others.

Comment: @DamianChrzanowski Thank you for your reminding,I have post it as a answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer to solve this question:

```
 (advice-add 'helm-swoop--edit :after #'evil-mc-mode)
 (advice-add 'helm-ag--edit :after #'evil-mc-mode)
```